# Proper implementation of node.js worker process on Heroku Cedar

Tags: node.js, heroku, worker

I have a process that needs to be run periodically - on a Rails app, it would be a worker process. Is there an equivalent for node.js on Heroku?

I'm currently using node-cron to run the periodic process on the same server as my web application. Issues here are:

- With only 1 web process, it won't run when the server idles
- It will block incoming connections while running
- When scaling, the process doesn't need to be run on multiple servers

If it is the case that Heroku simply does not yet handle this, I'm interested in seeing other Node PAAS providers solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must have missed the new Heroku Cedar app that does all of what you want - read more at

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js

Comment: The provided link has no mention of worker processes, so I'm still missing it. Elaborate please?

Comment: Cedar lets you define whatever processes/combinations you want to run in your application - whether it be a rails app, node, a worker etc etc http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar

Comment: I want to do the same thing that Frederick does - run a worker periodically. I know I can define a worker in my Procfile -- I have done so... but it is always running. So I tried having it execute a sleep, but it still continues to steadily consume Heroku cpu time. I know that node is evented: is there a way to have the worker Idle until it is awakened?